# What are the best practices for datatypes in Titan?

Tags: ibm-cloud, graph-databases, titan, ibm-graph

I'm creating a schema for my graph in IBM Graph that uses Titan.  I'm using the string datatype for most of my properties like name, address, etc.  What are the best practices for datatypes for properties like dates, timestamps, urls, and currency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently IBM Graph supports Integer, Float, Boolean, and String.So you'd need to map your data to one of these depending on whether you want to store formatted dates/currency and whether you want to compare these dates/currencies or not. Here's a link to IBM Graph's docs for reference

https://ibm-graph-docs.ng.bluemix.net/api.html#schema-apis